Conflct between QgsMapTool and QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature
I created a plugin with one QgsMapTool and one mapTooldigitilizedFeature. When I use the QgsMapTool before the mapTooldigitilizedFeature, I can't digitize my feature and my QGIS crashes.
self.current_tool = pointAjout(
            iface.mapCanvas(),
            iface.cadDockWidget(),
            QgsMapToolCapture.CapturePoint,
            "table_name",
            attr
        )
       
self.current_tool.digitizingCompleted.connect(self.current_tool.addFeature)

